# White space between parent and child div on some devices/browsers

Tags: css

I can't seem to remove the white space between the parent and child div.

[image]

It seems that this white line is not visible on all devices/browsers. The bug appears mostly on mobile

All sizes are specified in pixels so it doesn't seem to be half a pixel that is causing the bug.

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 80px;
}

.child {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the code you submitted, the top white space you mention is not visible.

Comment: As I said this white space is not visible on all devices Snorlax

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine I'm sorry, it was a mistake on my part, I thought I had to accept your edit for it to be effective, but obviously I did the opposite. I am a new user of SO...

Comment: @MaxHimes - No worries - all is forgiven! ;-) Thank you for adding the code to your question.

Comment: try using position absolute and set top: 0; right: 0

Comment: I'm also not seeing the issue but I can make some suggestions about the code because in some cases you get unexpected things happen when the code is not written well: don't put div tag inside a tag, always clear floating elements, the math on the .rating div doesn't add up (30px line-height + 7px padding bottom + 5px padding-top = 42 but the height is set to 40px)

Comment: Thank you @Raul, I still got the issue if I set height to a correct value. If I remove the a tag the problem is still here...

Comment: did you try with `box-sizing: border-box` for both div and `margin: -2px` for child div?

Comment: can you give an example on which devices/browsers this is happening? Would make it easier to reproduce it

Comment: I can see the problem in microsoft edge. test ok: with no border or with border >= 4px. with 2px there is a space on top and left side, with 3px there is space on all side. It seems a bug. On mobile test with android chrome and it work. Is this the behavior you see?

Answer (score 1):

> This white space is not visible on all devices, I don't know if it's related to the resolution or the browser [...] The problem seems to occur more often on mobile than on PC

It's a rounding discrepancy. Probably related to this line:

```
font-size: 1.75vw;
```

The browser on each device is calculating a number of pixels - on some devices the browser ends up with a result which is `1px` less than on other devices.

The fix (and I appreciate this will require some *design thinking*) is to use a **more explicit value** which is less likely to end up with a possible fraction of a pixel (which then needs to be rounded up or down).

I'd be tempted to start by giving `.rating`:

- an explicit `height`; and
- an explicit `line-height`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if I set the font size to 26 pixels, the problem is still there...

Comment: I've added a suggestion to the bottom of my answer above - it might help if you declare an explicit `height` and `line-height` for `.rating`.

Comment: I tried to set the heights of the children and the parents, to set the line-height but nothing solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

this could be a half pixel, which is being behaved differently with each browser,
it could be seen when zooming in, sometimes it couldn't

https://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/browsers-and-fractional-pixels/

Comment: Thanks for the share ! I simplify the problem it look like an half pixel is not causing the problem..

Comment: Yes by zoom-in into browser I can see the gap. But using outline or box-shadow instead of border, issue can be resolve.

Answer (score 1):

if you cannot remove it, hide it:

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 80px;
}

.child {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(0, 0, 0); /* a tiny box-shadow to cover the gap */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to use **outline** instead of **border**

```css
.parent {
  outline: 2px solid;
  outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 80px;
}

.child {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
   height: 80px;
}

.child {
   height: 80px;
   background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

That's more then enough

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not enough to show your confuse.

It should contain global CSS settings, like resized `font-size`, `line-height`, div's `display` attribute (like `inline-block`) ...

And in odd number DPR mobile screen, with the global font settings, this appearance will be more common.

Check and resize global or root settings.